# Defining a sequence for repeated use in foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach

I have a macro that does exactly what I want when I used it with a literal sequence, but not with a sequence that has been defined for reuse:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\begin{comment}
\end{comment}
\title{test1}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=latex, font=\sffamily]

\newcommand{\track}[3]{
\foreach \b [count=\i] in {#3}
{
  \node[#1] at (\i*3,#2) {\b};
}
}

\newcommand{\GA}{1,1,0,0,1}
\track{fill=red!50,thin}{0.0}{1,1,0,0,1}
\track{fill=green!50,thin}{0.5}{\GA}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does the 1,1,0,0,1 behave differently, and how can I get the red behavior to work with a macro?

Comment: If you call `\foreach\b in {...}` no expansion is done on the material in braces; you have to use `\foreach\b in \GA` (no braces) in order to have the macro evaluated before starting the loop.

Comment: I tried messing around with removing braces, no luck... I do need the foreach range to be a parameter, however, since I'm using a variety of different ones.

Comment: is there a way to force expansion at the right point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is one way, inspired by the way one does this in pgfplots.

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\begin{comment}
\end{comment}
\title{test1}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=latex, font=\sffamily]

\newcommand{\track}[3]{\edef\temp{#3}
\foreach \b [count=\i] in \temp
{
  \node[#1] at (\i*3,#2) {\b};
}
}

\newcommand{\GA}{1,1,0,0,1}
\track{fill=red!50,thin}{0.0}{1,1,0,0,1}
\track{fill=green!50,thin}{0.5}{\GA}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so edef forces expansion before usage? (confused)

Comment: @JasonS So am I. I just learned this trick from pgfplots, and even more so from the accompanying `TeX-programming-notes.pdf`.

Comment: @marmot Here is link to [`TeX-programming-notes.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/TeX-programming-notes.pdf)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks! But shouldn't this he comment for the OP? (These notes are also part of the TeLive distribution.)

Comment: You're right.  Here it goes @JasonS

Answer (score 3):

If you call `\foreach \b in {\GA}` there will be just one cycle. You need to remove the braces if you want to first evaluate the macro.

Possible solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\newcommand{\track}[3]{%
  \expandafter\trackaux\expandafter{#3}{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\trackaux}[3]{%
  \foreach \b [count=\i] in {#1} {
    \node[#2] at (\i*3,#3) {\b};
  }%
}

\newcommand{\GA}{1,1,0,0,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=latex, font=\sffamily]
\track{fill=red!50,thin}{0.0}{1,1,0,0,1}
\track{fill=green!50,thin}{0.5}{\GA}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oog... how does the `\expandafter` work? expand after what?

Comment: @JasonS One could write a book on `\expandafter`; it triggers expansion of the second token after it, so in this case we jump over the `{`.